# coloring the active link in asp links using code block available in w3schools

Tags: javascript, css, asp.net

I was trying to color the active link in my horizontal tab menu bar. I get the code block from this link ::
https://www.w3schools.com/howto/tryit.asp?filename=tryhow_js_active_element2

but when I applied to my ASP.NET web form, it is not working. The active tab is not colored as shown in the example.

```
<style type="text/css">
  .active, .btn:hover {
  background-color: #666;
  color: white;
}
</style>
<div id="myDIV">
        <ul>
            <li><a class="btn" href="block.aspx">block</a></li>
            <li><a class="btn" href="resen.aspx">resen</a></li>
            <li><a class="btn" href="total.aspx">total</a></li>
        </ul>
    </div>
 <script type="text/javascript">
    // Add active class to the current button (highlight it)
    var header = document.getElementById("myDIV");
    var btns = header.getElementsByClassName("btn");

    for (var i = 0; i < btns.length; i++) {
        btns[i].addEventListener("click", function () {
            var current = document.getElementsByClassName("active");
            alert(current);
            if (current.length > 0) {
                current[0].className = current[0].className.replace(" active", "");
            }
            this.className += " active";
        });
    }
</script>
```

I tried debugging the code, so used `alert` in for loop block for getting the value of `current` variable, it is showing `[object HTMLCollection]`. Only when I hover my mouse over the link, the color is changed.

What is the problem? Does I have to modify the java script code for ASP.NET web forms?

Comment: I think the issue might be because you're using links? The example you provided is using buttons, which doesn't effect the route in any way. If you're using links, you're routing to a new page which might reset the DOM, and removing the active class. Either change your `<a>` tags to `<button>` tags or if you want to route, then you should figure out some way to add an active class based on the current page you're viewing.

Comment: If you really want it exactly the same.. here is your solution: https://jsfiddle.net/ygaom1jw/